# How to deal with training set that overfits very easily

Tags: multiclass-classification, overfitting

I have a dataset consisting of 72 one-hot encoded (thus binary) features and 2.5K training examples. With this I am trying to solve a 10-class classification problem.

My main problem is that no matter which classification algorithm I use, the model overfits instantly to the train set while in the test all metrics seem pretty much bad, e.g. at best average f1-score around 0.18 and avg accuracy less than 20% average accuracy.

To deal with this I tried to reduce the number of features to 30 and finally to 10, simplified the models I use (mostly tree based). Also note that the split is done using stratification. Would it be a good idea to oversample ?
Note that I cannot reduce the number of target classes.

Example reports:

- Random Forest

  ```
            precision  recall   f1-score   support

      a       0.05      0.06      0.05        50
      b       0.15      0.17      0.16        42
      c       0.14      0.13      0.14        60
      d       0.14      0.18      0.16        77
      e       0.12      0.14      0.13        50
      f       0.26      0.21      0.23        33
      g       0.08      0.05      0.06        41
      h       0.14      0.10      0.11        51
      i       0.00      0.00      0.00        18
      j       0.20      0.21      0.20        78
  accuracy                           0.14       500
  macro avg      0.13      0.12      0.13       500
  weighted avg   0.14      0.14      0.14       500
  ```
- Gradient Boosted Trees with one-over-rest

  ```
        precision  recall  f1-score   support

  a       0.00      0.00      0.00        50
  b       0.08      0.02      0.04        42
  c       0.23      0.10      0.14        60
  d       0.13      0.42      0.20        77
  e       0.25      0.02      0.04        50
  f       0.00      0.00      0.00        33
  g       0.20      0.02      0.04        41
  h       0.00      0.00      0.00        51
  i       0.00      0.00      0.00        18
  j       0.17      0.44      0.24        78
  ```

  accuracy                           0.15       500
   macro avg      0.11      0.10      0.07       500
   weighted avg   0.12      0.15      0.10       500

Similar results I obtain for KNN and for Histogram Gradient boosting.

The same statistics for the training set are all almost 1.0.